# Variables not showing in short code

Tags: functions, shortcode

I am creating a shortcode that requires the use of two different variables `$banner` and `$banner__feature`. I know the variables are correct and they work because I tested them in another template file that I created.
As for the short code only the HTML from the displays on the website but the variables do not. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here and I need the Variables to show.

```
$banner = esc_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/banner.jpg' );

$banner__feature = esc_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/banner__feature--easter.jpg' );

function banner_shortcode() {

return '<div class="banner banner--call-now" data-parallax="scroll" data-bleed="100" data-image-src="' . $banner . '"> 
    <div class="banner__left">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="' . $banner__feature . '">
    </div>
    <div class="banner__center">
        <h2 class="banner__title">Call Now!</h2>
        <h1 class="banner__phone"><strong><a href="tel:1-570-877-8595"><strong>570-877-8595</strong></a></strong></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="banner__right">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="' . $banner__feature . '">
    </div>
</div>';

}
add_shortcode( 'banner', 'banner_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Just add both variables inside banner_shortcode() {} function before return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function banner_shortcode() {

    $banner = esc_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/banner.jpg' );
    $banner__feature = esc_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/banner__feature--easter.jpg' );

    return '<div class="banner banner--call-now" data-parallax="scroll" data-bleed="100" data-image-src="' . $banner . '"> 
        <div class="banner__left">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="' . $banner__feature . '">
        </div>
        <div class="banner__center">
            <h2 class="banner__title">Call Now!</h2>
            <h1 class="banner__phone"><strong><a href="tel:1-570-877-8595"><strong>570-877-8595</strong></a></strong></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="banner__right">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="' . $banner__feature . '">
        </div>
    </div>';

}
add_shortcode( 'banner', 'banner_shortcode' );
```